# awk command that compares strings for difference

Tags: string, awk

I have an gz file which contains values in $12 and $33, where they contains strings (ex $12: 33-A and $33: 33A), I am trying to create an awk command that reads the values and counts the number of times "-" is in $12 but not in $13.

I have: `gzcat test.gz | awk '{if ($12!=$33 && $12~/ -/ && $33!~/ -/) wc -l; else null} | wc -l'`

But that command doesn't seem to work and get me the outcome I would like.

Comment: Add to your question a sample data file with two columns that shows your program (that is, the non-compressed two-column version of your program) failing and tell us the result you expect.

Comment: Well, the string "33-A" will not match in your `$12~/ -/`, because it doesn't have a space before the hyphen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need to check equality separately since it's implied, and no need to use `wc`, `awk` is capable of counting

```
... | awk '$12~/-/ && $33!~/-/{count++} END{print count+0}'
```

ps. your script is not a valid `awk` script.  Also is the field `33` or `13`?

Comment: Great to know more about awk's capabilities, thanks for the answer!

Comment: `print count+0` to ensure numeric output even when no differences.